# Unable to find Android SDK Tools in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I have an Android Studio of version 4.1.1 in which

Android Studio -> Tools -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools
traversing to this does not show  **Android SDK Tools** to download,  Http proxy is selected to no proxy, no vpn is connected for internet.[This is my screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9e7i.png)
Is there a way to get Android SDK Tools option and download from the SDK tools? Are there any options in the IDE to enable and download? Any type of help will be considered. thank you!

Comment: on your shared screen, there is a check box name  "show package details" , click on that

Comment: I tried, but I still didn’t find Android SDK Tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's showed for me when I unchecked the "Hide Obsolete Packages" checkbox in the right bottom.

[Print od the SDK Tools window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xd5s9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the "**Hide Obsolete Packages**" and you should be able to find the SDK Tools.

[image]

If still not, you can check the "**SDK Update Sites**", to see whether these URLs are imported and nicely enabled
[image]